# Why can't my C# code find out when two objects are identical?

Tags: c#, object, tree, equals

This is a method for recursively searching through a binary tree that is filled with objects of the various child classes of the class Photo.

```
public void SearchForIdentical(Photo searched)
{
    SearchForIdentical(ref root, searched);
}

void SearchForIdentical(ref TreeNode current, Photo searched)
{
    try
    {
        if(current != null)
        {
            if(current.content.Equals(searched))
            {
                throw new PhotoAlreadyExistsException(searched);
            }
            SearchForIdentical(ref current.left, searched);
            SearchForIdentical(ref current.right, searched);
        }
    }
    catch (PhotoAlreadyExistsException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This photo already exists! Try a new one!");
    }
}
```

A 'photo' is defined by the value of its various arguments and properties (the child classes don't necessarily all have the same kind of arguments and properties). If the user types in a new photo, that is fully identical in all its arguments and properties with an existing one, this method should notice it, and throw an exception.

The problem is, it never happens. When I debugged it, it seemed the program never assigns true to the premise `current.content.Equals(searched)`, even when the two object is exactly identical.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Look up the difference between reference equality and value equality.

Comment: How is your `equals` method implemented? The default checks if the `GetHashCode` is equal. Two different objects never have the same hash code.

Comment: It's not clear why you're using `ref`, for starters... I'd also strongly avoid using this "throw an exception that you catch yourself" approach. Beyond those suggestions, please provide a [mcve] so that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Loetn: No, the default implementation checks whether the references are identical. Two different objects certainly *can* have the same hash code. By default it's incredibly unlikely that they would, but you shouldn't *assume* that it never will. From the docs: "The default implementation of the GetHashCode method does not guarantee unique return values for different objects. "

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you never override the `Equals()` method in the `Photo` class to do the comparisons of the properties you've described, your code will be doing an object reference equality comparison.

This would explain why when the properties are identical, the `Equals()` method returns `false`.